# Hyperlinks in Django Quill Editor are not displaying as expected

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls, quill

**Problem**
I added the Quill Editor to my Django admin. When I input hyperlinks in the QuillEditor such as "www.example.com", instead of creating the hyperlink exactly as I type it, the URL will appear on the template page as "localhost:8000/plants/www.example.com". Directing me to a broken page instead of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

**Context**
I've read through the [full quill documentation](https://github.com/leehanyeong/django-quill-editor) but I don't see a way to make sure hyperlinks added in the QuillEditor display without the project domain being prepended to the front of the hyperlink url.

Heres how I input the URL 'www.example.com' in the django admin:

[image]

Here is how the URL appears on the actual template page (you can see the url in the bottom left when I hover over it:
[image]

Maybe I need to edit something in the urls.py?

*plants > urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('plants/', include('plants.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your external links to start with "https://".

`https://www.example.com`

[image: No link]

[image: Yes link]

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Do you know why that happens? I'm trying to understand why the hyperlink was being prepended to my domain.

Comment: It is a standard behavior of the HTML href attribute. You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp